# Why can I not access an array element when I fill the array during subscribe?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
orderedAnalysis.forEach((analysis) => {
                this.analysisCenterService.getAnalysisDetails(analysis.id).subscribe(detail => {
                    analysis.detailed = detail;
                });
            });
console.log(orderedAnalysis[0]);
```

This is the result of the log statement:
[image: Log output]

But when I log `orderedAnalysis[0].detailed` the result will be undefined.

Why does this happen and how do I do this propely?

Comment: Can you please share your "getAnalysisDetails" function?

Comment: is getAnalysisDetails function an async operation like an http call? because your console.log statement will not print out the result

Answer (score 1):

It happens because HTTP call is asynchronous. So your code would looks like this:

```
orderedAnalysis.forEach((analysis, i) => {                    
     this.analysisCenterService.getAnalysisDetails(analysis.id)
        .subscribe(detail => {
                    analysis.detailed = detail;
                    console.log(analysis);
        });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

You can use `async` operator to `await` result your API call:

```
 async fooFunction() 
 {
     orderedAnalysis.forEach((analysis, i) => {                    
        let result = await this.analysisCenterService.getAnalysisDetails(analysis.id);
        analysis.detailed = result;
     });
     console.log(orderedAnalysis);
 }
```

If return type of `getAnalysisDetails` is `Observable`, then you can convert to `Promise` using `.toPromise` method:

```
 let result = await this.analysisCenterService.getAnalysisDetails(analysis.id).toPromise();
```

Comment: how can i use orderedAnalysis after subscribe done ?

Comment: @MhammedZghoul please, see my updated answer

Comment: How can I use `async/await` in subscribe?

Comment: `async/await` works with promises, subscribe in angular is of Observable type.

Comment: @AliWahab please, see my updated answer

Comment: @StepUp glad that you made changes.